# Render Drupal Block in a specific Bootstrap Pill - How?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to display a Views Block in a specific Bootstrap pill but hidden from all other pills on the page.  Right now the output shows up in all pills because it's associated with the Node or Content Type.  Can this be achieved?

Any guidance you can offer would be appreciated, I'm not even sure where to start at this point.